# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in name 11474" error after upgrading dom4j to 2.1.3 from 1.5.2

Tags: java, exception, upgrade, illegalargumentexception, dom4j

After upgrading dom4j to 2.1.3 from 1.5.2 I am getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in name 11474

if my name has number like below:

```
{"11474" : [{"name" : "dept",
"type" : "9",
"value" : "003|Engineering"},{"name" : "empid",
"type" : "5",
"value" : "spadmin"},{"name" : "empName",
"type" : "5",
"value" : "Administrator, Service Delivery"},{"name" : "reason",
"type" : "12",
"value" : "0"}]}
```

This was working fine in previous dom4j 1.5.2. If I add a prefix to 11474 like "string_11474", it is working fine.

```
{"string_11474" : [{"name" : "dept",
"type" : "9",
"value" : "003|Engineering"},{"name" : "empid",
"type" : "5",
"value" : "spadmin"},{"name" : "empName",
"type" : "5",
"value" : "Administrator, Service Delivery"},{"name" : "reason",
"type" : "12",
"value" : "0"}]}
```

But I am getting this data from external application which I cannot control. How to resolve this issue?
With this I am not able to upgrade from dom4j 1.5.2 to 2.1.3

If the tag has numeric I am getting the exception but it was working fine in 1.5.2

Comment: Your "data" looks like JSON. Are you using dom4j to parse JSON? Better to use a JSON parser, like GSON, no? Can you post the entire stack trace? Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: No, I am converting xml out of json data, yes, xml elements have to start with non-digit hence it is throwing error, but it was working fine with dom4j 1.5.2, the only difference is if I replace dom4j 1.5.2 to with dom4j 2.1.3 it is failing.
Below is my code, here the Node is dom4j node:
public List serializeToXml(String tag) {
List list = new ArrayList();
return list;
}
in the above function if the tag value starts with digit it is failing, if I add a prefix like this return "prefixstr_" + tag; it is working fine, this is after don4j upgrade, how to resolve this?

Comment: You don't need to repeat the question in a comment. And you should post code in the question (and **not** in a comment).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

dom4j 1.x didn't validate the Element name, dom4j 2.x added it. I don't think dom4j 2.x promised any backwards compatible behavior.